# Apache Drill - Slow Queries

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, apache-drill

I have the following storage plugin set-up in Drill:

```
{
  "type": "hive",
  "enabled": true,
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://hivemetastore.hostname.com:9083",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
  }
}
```

however, a simple

```
SELECT * FROM hive.table LIMIT 5;

...

5 rows selected (35.383 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:>
```

is taking over 30 seconds to respond. What am I missing / where should I begin the troubleshoot?

The Hive metastore server is the same as Drill right now. And there are less than 20,000 records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Only MapR Drill on the MapR sandbox should use the sparse storage plugin config you are using. In the sandbox, things are configured under the covers.

EMBEDDED METASTORE SERVICE

Assuming you are using a Drill installation, not the sandbox, and you're using the embedded metastore service (the default), configProps needs to look something like this (per the docs):

```
  "configProps": {
      "hive.metastore.uris": "",
      "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:<database>://<host:port>/<metastore database>",
      "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/tmp/drill_hive_wh",
      "fs.default.name": "file:///",
      "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
    }
```

Remove the "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://:" from your storage plugin config. That is for use with a remote hive metastore service.

The "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" might be a MySQL database. The Hive metastore service provides access to the physical DB like MySQL. MySQL stores the metadata. The "fs.default.name" is the file system location where the data is located.

The embedded metastore configuration is for testing only, and not for use in production systems [per the docs](http://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/#hive-embedded-metastore-configuration). For performance improvement, please configure the [remote metastore](http://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/#hive-remote-metastore-configuration). Also, check the compatibility of the version of Hive you are using. Open source Apache Drill 1.0 supports Hive 0.13. Drill 1.1 and later supports Hive 1.0.

REMOTE METASTORE SERVICE

If you're using the remote metastore, the "fs.default.name" should point to the main control node. Point to a NameNode, for example. If you're using MapR Drill, "fs.default.name" should be maprfs:///. The MapR FileClient figures out CLDB locations from mapr-clusters.conf. Start the metastore service, which is installed on top of Hive as a separate package:

```
hive --service metastore
```

The remote metastore config should look something like this if you're using open source Apache Drill:

```
{
  "type": "hive",
  "enabled": true,
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://mfs41.mystore:9083",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false",
    "fs.default.name": "maprfs://10.10.10.41/"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have the hive.metastore.uris value pointing at thrift to communicate with hive. Do you possibly mean the fs.default.name value needs to be set as well?

Comment: Edited the "answer" for clarification, but need more info. I'll check with an expert tomorrow to see if a config like yours could cause performance problems.

Comment: @catpaws any leads on this?

Comment: On 11/18, the "answer" was updated with info from an expert who dug into the code (no actual testing was done). Re: the 11/11 comment, yes fs.default.name needs to be set per revised docs: The fs.default.name value needs to be a URI that is available and capable of handling file system requests, e.g., "file:///, hdfs://, or hdfs://<hostname>:<port>. I heard about an untried, but possible a fix for an authentication (not Carl's problem) problem, suggested as a likely fix for other Hive connection problems: put the hive-site.xml file in Drill/Conf.